# Как получить данные из json (google map api)

Tags: node.js, google-maps-api

Ссылка на документацию с примером JSON: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start

Работаю на node.js, запрос отправляю при помощи request.
Я получаю аналогичный ответ, при помощи `let data = JSON.parse(body)` преобразую его для дальнейшей работы работы.

---

Проблема в том, что `console.log('data:', data.routes.legs);` возвращает undefined, а нужно получить данные из `data.routes.legs.distance.value`. Данные приходят (проверил). Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ оказался максимально простым.

```
data.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value
```